# Lottie-react-native not building on iOS 12 RN 0.60.4

Tags: ios, react-native, lottie

Trying to add Lottie into my react-native app but it keeps throwing errors.
Steps I followed based on original github and posts I found across internet:

(Btw, I don't use Cocoapods)

- Installed it by `yarn add lottie-react-native` and `yarn add
  lottie-ios@3.0.3`.
- Manually linked them, because for some reason my
  autolink isn't working (*i think it's an issue because i migrated from
  0.59 to 0.60.4* either that or I don't know how it's supposed to work).
- Added `LottieReactNative.xcodeproj` and `Lottie.xcodeproj` into **/Libraries** within my project.
- Added the `libLottie.a` and `libLottieReactNative.a` into **Link Binary With Libraries**.
- Added `Lottie.framework` into my target's **Embed Frameworks**.
- Don't know why there's a Lottie_iOS (Lottie) inside Target
  Dependencies, attempted removing it but it throws an error saying
  "Cannot find module Lottie" on some React Native Lottie files. So I
  added it back.
- Added the flag **LD_VERIFY_BITCODE** and set to "NO". Took from
  some stackoverflow.
- Also, went to XCode's *Project Settings* and
  changed the **Build System** to `Legacy Build System`.

Nothing seemed to work so far.
Versions:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "^0.60.4",
"lottie-ios": "^3.0.3",
"lottie-react-native": "^3.1.0",
```

Error thrown when build fails is:

```
Showing Recent Messages

Build target LottieLibraryIOS of project Lottie with configuration Debug

<unknown>:0: error: filename "TextCompositionLayer.swift" used twice: '/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/MyApp/node_modules/lottie-ios/lottie-swift/src/Private/LayerContainers/CompLayers/TextCompositionLayer.swift' and '/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/MyApp/node_modules/lottie-ios/lottie-swift/src/Private/LayerContainers/CompLayers/TextCompositionLayer.swift'
<unknown>:0: note: filenames are used to distinguish private declarations with the same name
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your manual linking. New autolinking process is using Cocoapods. If it's possible please create new project using `react-native init` and import your project to a new template or use [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.10&to=0.60.4) to upgrade your existing project template.

Comment: I see why then. Thanks. Made it work yesterday though doing it manually, took a while but it works! I will some day do the upgrade legit tho.